# Memory leak in a Node.js function that utilizes a mongoose model

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, memory-leaks

I have a 1000 line Node.js script that I use as a back-end server for a mobile game. I noticed it keeps guzzling up memory until it crashes and is automatically restarted by [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever). Following manuals, tutorials, and previous answers, I came to the conclusion that a huge memory leak happens in this function. I know this is the case because I increased this specific function's load and the memory leak speed intensified to 20kBps, and I am sure it is indeed a memory leak and not just natural memory usage because it crashes every several hours after memory usage hits 100% on my server.

```
var {Room} = require('./models/room');
//...
//...
//...
app.post('/updateRooms',(req,res)=>{
    let currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    Room.find({
        ip: req.body.ip,
        port: req.body.port
    }).then((result)=>{
        if(result.length==0){
            let room = new Room({
                ip: req.body.ip,
                port: req.body.port,
                location: req.body.location,
                difficulty: req.body.difficulty,
                playerAmount: req.body.playerAmount,
                lastUpdate: currentTime
            });
            room.save();
        } else {
            Room.findOneAndUpdate({
                ip: req.body.ip,
                port: req.body.port
            },{
                $set :{
                    difficulty: req.body.difficulty,
                    playerAmount: req.body.playerAmount,
                    lastUpdate: currentTime
                }
            }).then((r)=>{
                console.log(r); 
            });
        }
    result.length = 0;
    }).catch((e)=>{ console.log(e); });
});
```

This function is called by an external script by Axios, which sends an update about the room capacity of a game. There are several instances of said script (several rooms of the game) that keep sending updates about the amount of players they host.

The "{Room}" model is an ordinary mongoose model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Room = mongoose.model('Room', { 
  ip: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 1,
    trim: true
  },
  port: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 1,
  },
  location: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 1,
  },
  difficulty: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 1,
  },
  playerAmount: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  },
  lastUpdate: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  }
});

module.exports = {Room};
```

I tried emptying sent arrays (result.length=0) after use, but the memory leak keeps happening. Any idea what might cause this?

Comment: In the `POST /updateRooms` endpoint, trying ending the request-response cycle after creating a new or updating an existing Room. Something as simple as `res.end()` should work.